# Bootsrap 3: How to get a printed version of docs?

Tags: printing, twitter-bootstrap-3

Anyone have a way to get the Bootstrap 3 docs to print like they appear on the getbootstrap.com website? If you try to print the doc by using your browser's PRINT button, the docs don't come out too good.

I dont' have access to the internet at work, so I need a good paper copy of the Bootstrap 3 docs!

Comment: Please re-consider opening this back up for discussions. As you can see my latest comment below, it's an issue I, nor anyone else, can solve at the moment and I think a good problem to ask the SO community to help with. I'm not looking for a tool or off-site resource, I'm looking for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try using Google Chromes print function. I just tested it and it seems to be looking pretty good!

Another way I can think of is the Safari reader function. There is a button in the head bar of safari on the right hand side that states "Reader" and gives you a pretty good format of the sites text. This would be the way I'd do it.

Hope that helps in any way.

Comment: Are you talking about the generic built-in PRINT menu item in Chrome? That's what I did to make my copy but lots of the design elements in the document did not print too well (very light colors were used in CSS that does not show well in browser prints).

Comment: Hm. As far as I could see it seems to be not so common to print the document. But I still have one idea. Have you tried to save the document as pdf file and then take it to work? You could still open it on your pc without internet and colors should be fine.

Comment: The problem is that saving to PDF seems to look exactly as if it was printed, thus not very good. Try it and see. I'll try it again. I wonder if there's a tool out that basically prints to paper (or PDF) EXACTLY as one sees it in the browsers. Of course, I could take screenshots and print it that way, but there are hundreds of pages!

Comment: @patrick It's a lot of documentation (and many pages long), which is why it normally isn't downloaded by developers. -Steven

Comment: Here's a generated version of the CSS page as it appears on the site: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jjuiog4ptudt3nr/getbootstrap-com.pdf. I hope  this helps @redshift.

Comment: Stevenson, thanks for that. however, you are having the same problem I am. Notice how much of the code examples are stripped out when you convert to PDF (same happens when you print directly from webpage). For example, go to the FORMS section of the documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) and then look at the example code between the FORMS BASIC EXAMPLE and the INLINE FORM and you'll notice it got stripped out when you converted to PDF. I need that code when I print. I am even looking for a cheatsheet. There is nothing out there..not even a book I can buy.

Answer (score 1):

It's not practical to try to print Bootstrap's complete documentation. If you're trying to learn the basics, then I'd highly suggest finding a resource in pdf format such as this one [.Bootstrap's Cheatsheet](https://dresssed.s3.amazonaws.com/bootstrap_cheatsheet.pdf) However, without learning the basics, that won't work either. I'd really suggest visiting Treehouse. They have a video here: http://teamtreehouse.com/library/treehouse-workshops/building-websites-with-bootstrap-3 that does a good job. They also have excellent courses that I believe they allow you to view for free. They'll give you enough info to make that cheatsheet make more sense. That's how I learned.

Steven

Comment: I am aware of the cheatsheet you suggested, however, that cheatsheet is not the latest version of Bootstrap (e.g. the 'span' for columns vs the newer 'col-md-4')