# Bootsrap 3: How to get a printed version of docs - workaround

Tags: printing, twitter-bootstrap-3

Often I will want printed versions of docs so I can read them in comfort, without straining my eyes reading text on a screen and sitting in an uncomfortable office chair for long periods of time.

Sometimes docs, like the Bootstrap docs, are important to be printed with the formatting / page css included (duh - it's Bootstrap), since that's what the docs are there for... to show you how to style things.

How do I get a printed copy of the bootstrap docs, for instance, the [css page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), while preserving the layout and styling?

Comment: Connect a printer to your computer and print the docs out through - lets say - chrome...? :-)

Comment: Design your page with a proper setting for sizing in bootstrap for print. If it is not your page then contact the webmaster or live with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a somewhat inglorious workaround - when printing, choose **A3** or **Tabloid** paper size with **Landscape orientation**. Also, you may need to print the entire page instead of just a region of text to get the formatting just right.

These paper sizes more closely resemble a monitor size / resolution, so the page will print with more of the CSS preserved as shown on a larger computer screen.

I would have answered this on the previously-asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151706/bootsrap-3-how-to-get-a-printed-version-of-docs), but it was Closed due to being "off-topic".